# Uneditable trailing text in textarea

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been fighting with this for a couple of days to no avail.

I  need to have a textarea with uneditable text trailing on the end.

Here is a fiddle with the text in the beginning of the text area, the requirement is to have it on the end. Anyone have any insight how to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/codemonkeytony/3ew5h6bf/7/

```
 var partialApp = angular.module("partialApp", []);

 partialApp.directive('partialReadonly', function () {
 return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
         elem.on('keypress, keydown', function (event) {
            console.log(scope.bbb);
          console.log(event);
             var readOnlyLength = attrs["partialReadonly"].length;
             if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39)) && ((elem[0].selectionStart < (scope.bbb - readOnlyLength )) || ((elem[0].selectionStart != (scope.bbb - readOnlyLength )) && (event.which == 8)))) {
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
         });
         $(window).load(function () {
                 elem[0].value = attrs["partialReadonly"];
             });
         }
     };
 });
```

Comment: Please link to the fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the logic on keypress event handler. Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz6npus0/2/), if you want this behaviour.

```
partialApp.directive('partialReadonly', function () {
 return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
         var readOnlyText = attrs["partialReadonly"];
         var readOnlyLength = readOnlyText.length;
         var ele = elem[0];
         elem.on('keypress, keydown', function (event) {
             var actualTextLength = ele.value.length - readOnlyLength;
             var readOnlyTextStartIndex = actualTextLength; 
             if (elem[0].selectionStart > readOnlyTextStartIndex) {
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
         });
         $(window).load(function () {
             elem[0].value = attrs["partialReadonly"];
         });
     }
 };
 });
```

Comment: It works nicely there is still the issue of pasting, when I highlight a piece on the uneducable text and paste the text will paste changing the uneditable text. right clicking and pasting also breaks it.

Comment: In such cases, rather than hacking the things, if possible, you can put the non-editable text outside the textbox and put the editable text in variable width textbox or something.